# YII form input with html5 required="required"

Tags: php, html, yii

I have one application in Yii and its creating one field for email input,
the code in view is

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model, 'email', $model->getHtmlOptions('email')); ?>
```

I want to add `required="required"` in the same field.

Even I don't know from where this `$model->getHtmlOptions('email'))` is coming from.

I don't know how to do it. I've searched all day in google but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be use some third part extension or behavior with getHtmlOptions() method. Concerning $form->textField signature third parameter should be an array. So to keep getHtmlOptions working and add required attribute we need to merge two arrays:

```
<?php echo $form->textField(
    $model,
    'email',
    CMap::mergeArray(
        $model->getHtmlOptions('email'),
        array('required' => true)
    );
?>
```

Hope it will work.